# Assign value to input without v-model and without databinding

Tags: data-binding, vue.js, vuejs2

In my v-for i need to initialize some input field with some text WITHOUT binding it to the object. Currently i'm trying:

```
<div v-for="item in allItems">
  <input type="text" class="header-title" value="item.name"></input>
</div>
```

but item.name is printed in the input instead of the item name. How to accomplish this?

Comment: Change `value="item.name"` to `:value="item.name"`

Comment: @Nora OP does not want use binding

Comment: Am I the only not clear with this question?

Comment: What do you mean by "WITHOUT binding "? Read-only?

Answer (score 9):

`v-model` is just syntactic sugar for `:value` and an event, usually `@input`.  See docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events).

You can pass a noop  function `() => {}` to cancel the value update or do whatever you want with the new value, maybe assign it to another object.

Note: `<input>` elements are void, they do not require a closing tag.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      allItems: [{ name: 'foo' },{ name: 'bar' }]
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in allItems">
    <input type="text" class="header-title" :value="item.name" @input="() => {}">
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have your input show value of `item.value` by only using the `ref` attribute.

Just add `ref=''` and map it's values to the inputs value, inside your mounted function.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data () {
    return {
      allItems: [
        {name: 'foo'},
        {name: 'bar'}
      ]
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    let self = this; 
    this.$refs.inp.map( (m, k) => {
      m.value = self.allItems[k].name
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in allItems">
    <input type="text" class="header-title" value="item.name" ref='inp'></input>
  </div>
</div>
```